# css content center inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have

```
<div class="dashboard_content-area">
  <div class="infinity-loader" style="justify-content: center;">
    <div class="la-ball-beat" style="justify-content: center;">
        <div class="dreikanter la-ball-beat__item">1</div>
        <div class="dreikanter la-ball-beat__item">2</div>
        <div class="dreikanter la-ball-beat__item">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it is still not centered inside of div. I have bootstrap enabled as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to the `la-ball-beat` class, that should center your content.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, then why don't you just use a Bootstrap centering option?

I'd have to see more of what you are trying to center, but take a look at Offset with Bootstrap. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score -1):

Use absolute positioning and measure the offset in pixels using your favourite photo editor. Iterate until it's in the middle.

Comment: :D u funny. But I don't have a ruler :(